# Silverlight 4 ip camera video player or streamer

Tags: silverlight-4.0, media-player, mediaelement, ip-camera

I'm having a problem with the ZOT IP cam. I can play my local webcam on `mediaElement`, but I must take video from the IP. I tried to give the cam IP to `mediaElement` via `Uri` but that doesn't open. I need some help with this situation. Any suggestion for silverlight IP cam, Video streamer or silverlight video player?